# Import SpringSource into IDEA.But had a error "Unrecognized VM option 'MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m'"

Tags: spring, jvm, gradle, jvm-arguments

I want to import Spring-framework into IDEA. 
I followed the document, and run the following command, but I had a error:

```
spring-framework>gradlew.bat :spring-oxm:compileTestJava cleanIdea idea

Unrecognized VM option 'MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m'
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

What's wrong?

My OS is Win7. JDK version is as following :

```
>java -version
java version "1.6.0_38"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

>javac -version
javac 1.6.0_38
```

Comment: what's you jdk version?

Comment: ```
>java -version
java version "1.6.0_38"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

>javac -version
javac 1.6.0_38
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @VMN said, MaxMetaspaceSize is supported in Java 8 and have [bugs](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-gc-dev/2013-March/006281.html).

**You can try one of this:**

1)[Download JDK8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) and set it to you environment.

2)Edit `gradlew.bat`(windows) or `gradlew`(linux), remove the VM option `MaxMetaspaceSize`.

Comment: In case you are configuring WildFly, remove option from installation file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Cause of error is in Java 8 option "MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m", that not supported in early versions. Spring developers use this option in master branch.
After switching to the 3.2.x branch project was successfully imported.

Answer (score 0):

You have three choice to slove this problem

1)use **JDK8** as your enviroment;

2)ignore or delete "set GRADLE_OPTS=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxHeapSize=256m %GRADLE_OPTS%" in **gradle.bat**;

3)choose another branch like 3.2.x